# Correlation between factors of two products of conjugate complex numbers?

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers

Is the following correct - if so, how do you prove it?

$(a_1 + i\cdot b_1)(a_1 - i\cdot b_1) = (a_2 + i\cdot b_2)(a_2 - i\cdot b_2); \{a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2\} \in \mathbb{R}; i \text{ is the imaginary unit}$

$\exists k \in \mathbb{R}: (((a_1+i\cdot b_1) = k\cdot(a_2+i\cdot b_2))\land((a_1-i\cdot b_1) = \frac{1}{k}\cdot(a_2-i\cdot b_2)))$
$\phantom{\exists k \in \mathbb{R}: } \lor$
$\phantom{\exists k \in \mathbb{R}: } (~~~~(~~(a_1+i\cdot b_1) = k\cdot(a_2-i\cdot b_2)~~)\land(~~(a_1-i\cdot b_1) = \frac{1}{k}\cdot(a_2+i\cdot b_2)~~)~~~~)$

In words: If two products of conjugate complex numbers yield the same result, then  one factor of the first product is $k$ times one factor of the second product while the other factor of the first product is $\frac{1}{k}$ times the other factor of the second product **for some** $\mathbf{k \in \mathbb{R}}$.

Edit/additional remark:

Please forget the question: Under the assumption that such $k$ exists, you can examine real and imaginary parts separately which reveals:
$(~~(a_1=a_2=b_1=b_2=0)\land(k\in R)\land(k\neq0)~~)\lor\\
(~~((a_2\neq0)\lor(b_2\neq0))\land(|a_1|=|a_2|)\land(|b_1|=|b_2|)\land ((k=1)\lor(k=-1))~~)$

Besides this examples where no such $k$ exists can easily be constructed by "multiplication" of primitive pythagorean triples— e.g.:
$3^2+4^2=5^2\land 5^2+12^2=13^2 \implies \\ (3\cdot13)^2+(4\cdot13)^2=(5\cdot5)^2+(12\cdot5)^2\Leftrightarrow39^2+52^2=25^2+60^2\Leftrightarrow\\
(39 + i\cdot52)(39 - i\cdot52) = (25 + i\cdot60)(25 - i\cdot60)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is false.

Call the common value of your product $m$.  Your conjecture implies that if $(c+di)(c-di)=m$, then $\frac{c}{d}$ has exactly two values: $\pm\frac{a_1}{b_1}$ (if $b_1=0$, the values are $\pm\infty$).

But for any $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, $$(\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta})(\cos{\theta}-i\sin{\theta})=1$$  And $\frac{\cos{\theta}}{\sin{\theta}}=\tan{\theta}$, which attains infinitely many values.